# Power supply and motor drivers problem.

Tags: power-supply, driver, stepper-motor

I have a 24 volt 6.5 amp power supply which I am using to power a stepper motor driver which is rated to 3.5 amps max. Will directly connecting the two cause a problem or will the motor driver only pull the required amps?

Comment: How do you limit the current to 3.5 amps?

Comment: the power supply is your bank and your motor is the budget.

Comment: Question is unanswerable as is.... What voltage and current rating are the motors. What does "driver rated at 3.5A Max" actually mean... It blows up if you go over that, or it shuts down if you try to suck more current than that....

Answer (score 1):

It will only pull the required current from the power supply.

It might only be a problem if you exceed the 6.5A value: in that case the supply can for example limit the current to that value by lowering the output voltage, or turn off the output, or blow a fuse (depending on how your power supply works).

Comment: Okay that is what I thought, the problem I am having is that the power supply works fun when there is no component on it. But when I put the motor driver on the power supply the said power supply will only give burst of power, shut off give another burst of power and repeat.

Comment: I guess, it could be a starting current problem: when powering the motor, you could have a large current transient. Perhaps it exceeds for a small time the 6.5A output capability, so that the supply goes in protection mode. Try to check the current waveform.

Comment: Um.... the OP never stated what voltage the stepper motors are rated at in the original question. This answer is ONLY true if the motors are rated at 24V. If they are 12V motors or not wired in whichever mode the rating was made at, the current could be whatever the supply has to offer. In which case the driver will likely burn out, or the motor might fail, or the PSU will. @NicholasBradley

Comment: Also.. "driver which is rated to 3.5 amps max" is meaningless without more description. @NicholasBradley

Comment: So the Stepper motor driver is 3amp output and 10-35 volt input  so that is why the 24volt input. And the motor is a Nema 23 - 90 with 3.5 Volts motor phase and 2 amp per phase current.